# Помогите пожалуйста разорбраться с методам elementFromPoint()?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Проблема заключается в том, что есть два дива, один меньше другой больше. Большой постоянно перемещается и я хочу знать, когда маленький будет находиться в области координатов большого. Использую вот такой код, но на выходе у меня везде null. Почему так происходит.

```js
let boxBig = document.querySelector(".boxBig ");
let y = 50;
let x = 20;
setInterval(() => {
  boxBig.style.top = (parseInt(boxBig.style.top) || 0) + y + "px";
  let elem = document.elementFromPoint(y, x);
  let res = elem.closest(".boxSmall");
  console.log(res);
}, 1000);
```

```css
.boxBig {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}

.boxSmall {
  border: 5px solid rgb(231, 26, 91);
  position: fixed;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 400px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxBig"></div>
<div class="boxSmall "></div>
```

Comment: Можно весь код в студий?

Comment: Добавил, js и html

Comment: так `null` у тебя после `closest`, а не после `elementFromPoint`

Comment: `closest` возвращает ближайший родительский элемент, соответствующий данному селектору....таковых у тебя нет. поэтому он возвращает NULL

Comment: вот и весь сказ

Comment: ну так правильно, он ищет ближайший элемент по координатом elementFromPoint(), когда большой блок настигает маленький, closest все ровно не видит его и возвращает null

Comment: добавь свои стили. Сейчас у тебя никакой блок не двигается, соответственно никакие координаты не меняются

Comment: также перепутаны параметры, передаваемые в `document.elementFromPoint`. Ввиду отсутствия стилей невозможно узнать какие координаты блока на самом деле.

Comment: _он ищет ближайший элемент по координатом elementFromPoint()_ - нет, он ищет именно **родительский** элемент, и если ты не попал в свой блок - ты его никогда не получишь, как бы рядом с ним ты не кликнул.

Comment: Добавил стили. Помогите пожалуйста решить этот вопрос!) @Grundy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в неверном указании координат:

1. перепутаны местами `x` и `y`
2. проверяется одна и та же точка, находящаяся вне маленького квадрата, поэтому результат всегда `null`.

Для решения достаточно менять проверяемую точку вместе с координатами большого квадрата, а так же подобрать такие координаты, чтобы точка при движении все-таки могла попасть внутрь маленького квадрата

```js
let boxBig = document.querySelector(".boxBig ");
let current = document.getElementById("current");
let y = 50;
let x = 40;

current.style.top = `${y - 1 + 15}px`;
current.style.left = `${x - 1 + 5}px`;


let timer = setInterval(() => {
  let currentY = (parseInt(boxBig.style.top) || 0) + y;
  current.style.top = `${currentY - 1 + 15}px`;
  current.style.left = `${x - 1 + 5}px`;

  boxBig.style.top = currentY + "px";
  let elem = document.elementFromPoint(x + 5, currentY + 15);
  let res = elem;
  console.log(res);
  if (res != boxBig) clearInterval(timer);
}, 1000);
```

```css
.boxBig {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}

.boxSmall {
  border: 5px solid rgb(231, 26, 91);
  position: fixed;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 30px;
}

#current {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="current"></div>
<div class="boxBig"></div>
<div class="boxSmall"></div>
```

Comment: Еще один глупый вопрос, а зачем здесь новый блок  -  current @Grundy ?

Comment: @user503400, это чтобы было видно у какой точки ты вызываешь `elementFromPoint`

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за такое понятное объяснение. Теперь мне все понятно! @Grundy